# All six of them

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual

This sequence of grids is arranged in alphabetical order *but* one grid is empty as you can see. All the others are complete.

**How should you fill in the squares in order for this empty grid to be complete?**

---

[image]

Comment: Is the grid with a red square part of the sequence?

Comment: No, it's not. That just worked as a guide

Comment: I would argue that the forth also have another option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> [image]
>
>
>  Because these are the moves that can be made by chess pieces, missing the queen

Comment: Well done! Faster than expected